# StateT for Configuration File

Tags: haskell, state, ini, monad-transformers

I am trying to read the Configuration file sections using StateT monad. But having some trouble. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

```
readSections :: StateT FilePath IO [T.Text] 
readSections = do
    path <- get
    config <- readIniFile path
    case config of
        Left _ -> put [T.empty]
        Right ini -> put (sections ini)
```

Comment: What are your problems?

Comment: Why are you using `StateT`? It doesn't really seem relevant to this goal. Just take the path as a function argument and use plain `IO`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that you're trying to use a state of type `FilePath` as both the input configuration filename to the function using `get` and the output list of section names using `put`.  At least for the `put`, the types aren't correct.  A `FilePath` can't be a list of section names `[T.Text]`.

Since your monadic return value is `[T.Text]`, perhaps you meant to use `return` instead of `put`.  You also have an additional problem because `readIniFile` is an `IO` action, not a `StateT FilePath IO` action so you'll need to use `liftIO` to lift it into your monad.  The following will typecheck, for example:

```
import Data.Ini
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Text as T

readSections :: StateT FilePath IO [T.Text]
readSections = do
    path <- get
    -- need to lift this action into StateT FilePath IO
    config <- liftIO $ readIniFile path
    case config of
        -- use "return", not "put" here
        Left _ -> return [T.empty]
        Right ini -> return (sections ini)
```

However, it's probably not necessary to use a state here.  A state shouldn't be used just to pass input to a function (or pass output back out of it) -- that's what normal function arguments (and return values) are for.  So, you could rewrite this as:

```
readSections' :: FilePath -> IO [T.Text]
readSections' path = do
  config <- readIniFile path
  case config of
    Left _ -> return [T.empty]
    Right ini -> return (sections ini)
```